# Unable to see custom response in Exception Handler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a custom exception handler in asp.net core 2.1 application

```
    public  class ExceptionHandler
        {

            private readonly RequestDelegate next;

            public ExceptionHandler(RequestDelegate next)
            {
                this.next = next;
            }

            public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
            {
                try
                {
                    await next(context);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
                }
            }

            private static async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HttpClientResponseContract
                            {
                                ErrorMessage = exception.Message,
                                ResponseCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                            });
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;


                await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }
}
```

I have registered this middleware in startup.cs

```
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandler>();
```

In the event of an exception, I can hit the breakpoint in this class but I dont get the result object in the response. In fact, I get nothing except 500 Internal Server Error in the response.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is your current `Startup.cs`? Make sure you add `app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandler>();` after `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`.

Comment: I had commented out app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() in Startup.cs file. But still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandler>();

    //rest service

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "catalog",
            template: "Catalog/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    });
}
```

Comment: I tried adding app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandler>(); before app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() But I still get 500 Internal server error after   await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);

Comment: @RohitRamname is there any demo to reproduce your issue?